# query to return a row from a table from multiple rows from the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

My table looks like

```
ID    AB_ID   VALUES
1      2        20
2      2        10
3      2        30
4      2        60
```

I would like to create a query to return

```
AB_ID     value1     value2     value3     value4
  2        20          10        30           60
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: What database engine? Do you always have 4 rows per AB_ID? Do value1 to value4 correspond to the ID column ascending per group of AB_ID?

Comment: Pivot clause is what you need

Comment: @ElVieejo: maybe not.. we don't have enough information

Comment: Seems a pivot. Why don't you do it in the client app instead of SQL? It should be more portable...

Comment: For multiple values of `AB_ID`, are the values of `ID` limited to some subset, or can `ID` take on absolutely any value for different values of `AB_ID`?

Comment: ID is the primary key and AB_ID is a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know there are going to be four rows per `AB_ID`, you should be able to do a pivot along these lines

```
SELECT ab_id,
       MAX( CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN values ELSE NULL END ) value1,
       MAX( CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN values ELSE NULL END ) value2,
       MAX( CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN values ELSE NULL END ) value3,
       MAX( CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN values ELSE NULL END ) value4
  FROM (SELECT ab_id,
               values,
               rank() over (partition by ab_id 
                                order by id) rn
          FROM your_table)
 GROUP BY ab_id
```

If you are using Oracle 11.2, you should be able to use the `PIVOT` keyword as well.  I'm not sure what version of Oracle you're using though.